# How do I sort by Case Type Title instead of id in a Drupal View?

Tags: civicase, drupal-views

We frequently need to sort Drupal Views by Case Type.

It works, but sorts by id not the title field.

I believe it has to do with the pseudoconstant references in civicrm.case.inc and civicrm.core.inc.

I think that approach is fine except when it's time to sort and/or filter.

In Drupal Views, all exposed filters are sorted by id.  So when a user tries to filter by Case Type they get an unordered list of Case Types that to their eyes are in a very random order and is more difficult to use.

Same thing if I sort the overall view by case type.  Cases appear in non-alphabetical order and require a bit more concentration to digest them.

Is there a way to sort these fields in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution of all.  As mentioned here: [Civicase Dashboard - reordering case types](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/civicase-dashboard-reordering-case-types)

I changed the weights in the table to easily change the order.

Why the heck didn't I think of that?

It would be nice to be able to change the weight within the Case Type UI.

**Update**
While the weight solution worked nicely for the select lists in Views exposed filters, it would not sort the results by case type name only by id.

For example, a view listing case types came out like this:
Case Type C
Case Type E
Case Type A
Case Type D
Case Type B

The issue appears to be that the civicrm_case_type table is never exposed to views.

So I added this to civicrm.case.inc:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------
  // CIVICRM Case Type Names are here, base tabling it up.
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  $data['civicrm_case_type']['table']['group'] = t('CiviCRM Case Type Names');

  $data['civicrm_case_type']['table']['base'] = array(
    // Governs the whole mozilla
    'field' => 'id',
    'title' => t('CiviCRM Case Type Names'),
    'help' => t("View displays CiviCRM Case Type Names"),
  );

  // Explain how this table joins to others.
  $data['civicrm_case_type']['table']['join'] = array(
    // Directly links to case table.
    'civicrm_case' => array(
      'left_field' => 'case_type_id',
      'field' => 'id',
    ),
  );

  //CiviCRM Case Type - FIELDS

  //Case Type Title
  $data['civicrm_case_type']['title'] = array(
    'title' => t('Case Type Name'),
    'real field' => 'title',
    'help' => t('The Name of the Case Type'),
    'field' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
    'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'argument' => array(
     'handler' => 'views_handler_argument',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );
```

Which joins the table and only exposes the title field to Views.

After I applied this, the same view printed out:
Case Type A
Case Type B
Case Type C
Case Type D
Case Type E

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Civicrm Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) in Drupal?  It should allow you to expose anything as a drupal entity but I haven't verified this case.

Comment: In my limited interaction with CiviCRM Entities, it did not seem very tightly integrated with CiviCase.  Perhaps I'll take another look, but I think this is one of those things that should be in core.

Comment: IMO civicrm entities should be in core rather than views :) can't say specifically about cases although I may need to use it in an upcoming project so pls update here with any learnings or questions.

Comment: I agree and I will!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a non-civi drupal site (since this is a general drupal views problem). I worked around it with this inelegant junk in my custom module:

`function mymodule_views_pre_render($view) {
    if ($view->name == 'the_name_of_the_view') {
        foreach ($view->result as $i => $r) {
            // Might not need to loop - idea is to do your own custom sorting and put result into some $new_result variable
        }
        $view->result = $new_result;
    }
}`

Note it's drupal 6. Might have to fiddle for drupal 7. You may want to use your favorite technique to examine $view->result to see what it looks like first.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will require a patch to the CiviCRM Views code. If you can offer to do so, you could open a ticket in JIRA and supply the fix

Comment: I'll poke around, but I fear it may be out of my league.

Comment: Ticket [CRM-17285](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17285) added and fix supplied.