# Civicase Dashboard - reordering case types

Tags: wordpress, civicase

Running Wordpress 4.3 , and Civi 4.6.8.

My organisation currently has around a dozen Case types, and we will soon have more. 
In the CiviCase Dashboard, these are listed under "Summary of Involvement" Table.
We would like to re-order the table to make it more logical for users to find the right one. The same issue applies to the Case Type Drop down when creating a new case.

My primary issue is - Can anyone suggest the best method for reordering these case-types?

Currently I cannot understand any logic to the order the they are listed - not by the order they were created, nor alphabetically, and not as i tried, by changing the 'weight' field as found in the db. (What even is this used for?)

Thanks

Comment: Browsing the code it should be by the weight in civicrm_case_type - see the call to CRM_Case_PseudoConstant::caseType() in CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCasesSummary() - the caseType function specifies by weight - and then the array_merge near the end should preserve that order. So you could do a php sort after the array_merge, but it seems like it should be by weight based on the code as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Comment from Demerit is correct. 
Rewriting the order of 'weight' in  civicrm_case_type - then flushing civi and browser cache - correctly reordered the lists.
(I'm not exactly sure why this didn't seem to work the first time) 
Thanks